# “Damaged goods” (about suffering people)

Tags: traduction, anglais

Context is a school where a teacher had a rough life (she's an orphan) and one of her students has also lived through difficult times.
She says: “We were both damaged goods”.
I know the phrase perfectly well but struggle to find a proper French equivalent.

- “tous deux abîmés par la vie”
- “tous deux des rebuts”
- “déchets”
  ??

Answer (score 4):

*Déchets* or *rebuts* are not appropriate in such case; they are too pejorative meaning they are both "non recoverable".

*Abîmés par la vie* is idiomatic but I would prefer *On a pas été gâtés par la vie*.

You might also simply translate it by:

> On a tous les deux vécu des moments douloureux.

After being informed *damaged goods* is actually strong and might be derogatory, here are some new suggestions:

> On est tous les deux des accidentés de la vie
>
> On a tous les deux été brisés / des cas désespérés / des [cas sociaux](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cas_social).

In slang, that might also be:

> On a été des [cassos](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cassos) tous les deux.

Comment: C'est juste mais "damaged goods" est aussi très péjoratif. Si les élèves ne l'avaient pas employé eux/elles-mêmes ce serait inacceptable comme description d'une personne, à mon avis.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Merci ! Je ne pensais pas que l'expression anglaise était si péjorative.

Comment: Oui, en effet je dirais que le sens indiqué dans la question n'est pas vraiment ce que signifie le terme. Plutôt que « quelqu'un qui a beaucoup souffert » il s'agit d'une personne dont la « valeur » s'est dépréciée suite à une expérience négative, une personne non-désirable à cause de ce qu'on lui a fait. Pour « add insult to injury » !

Comment: Merci. Abîmés par la vie me semble juste.

Comment: Yes, *abîmés par la vie* is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I find the previous answer absolutely correct; but I'd like to add some more familiar options:

- *On revient de loin*
- *On ne l'a pas eu facile*

Answer (score 1):

Ma suggestion (et variantes) :

> La vie ne nous a pas épargnés !
>
> La vie ne nous a pas épargnés, tous les deux.
>
> On n'a pas été épargnés par la vie, tous les deux !